# How to have tomcat use folder with extension .jar as jar files?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, jar

I have in Eclipse web application project that depends from other projects.
When I run debug on embedded Tomcat  in lib folder that Eclipse copied not jars, but folders with names like:

```
dependent_lib1.jar
dependent_lib2.jar
dependent_lib3.jar
....................
```

So web application  don't start because didn't found some files. When I manually deleted all these folders and manually copy jar files - all works.
Does it possible ask Eclipse (or maven - this is maven project) to copy jars or ask Tomcat use folders like jars?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I think it should be done with maven:

1. If the other projects are also maven projects, export them as maven artifacts in your local repository. A nice article is [Maven Deploy Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) - If they are not maven projects you should manually generate the jar files and add them to the repository, some information can be found at [Best way to create a maven artifact from existing jar](http://best-way-to-create-a-maven-artifact-from-existing-jar)
2. Add the exported artifacts as dependencies to your project. A lot of details can be found at [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse cannot do it as its just an IDE, you would need use A BUILD SCRIPT using ANT(Copy tag should do it) and run it before you start your server.

Check this for more details:
http://www.javabeat.net/tips/103-writing-simple-ant-build-script.html